# Go Back to home screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have created button for home like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem * addButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Home" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(GoToHome:)];
    [navItem setLeftBarButtonItem:addButton];
```

GoToHome function has only one line i.e:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

but when i click the Home button it shows no action (not working)

Comment: can you post your goToHome method entirely please ?

Comment: check whether self.navigationController is nil or not?

Comment: Is your goToHome method actually being called? Try an NSLog to check.

Comment: -(IBAction) GoToHome:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

Comment: @ade yes it is going to gotohome method, i checked it by NSLog

Comment: Do you have your button linked up to your IBAction in your .xib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this inside your GoToHome method

```
 [self.parentViewController.parentViewController.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: will this work if i m on 4th screen and want to goto first screen.

Comment: This is horrendous coding. Just because it "works" (ie does what you want) doesn't mean it is "correct".

Answer (score 1):

have you connected the button code with the IB button? that can happen a lot and with everyone..!!

Comment: I am creating the button at runtime,

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]  initWithTitle:@"Home" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(GotoTopScreen)];
```

`self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;`

```
-(void)GotoTopScreen{
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The best way to create a navigation controller is to create it in appDelegate and access it as appDelegate.navigationController. Then those nil object issues do not come.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
UIBarButtonItem *flipButtons = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"   
            style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered  target:self 
            action:@selector(GotoTopScreen)];
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = flipButtons;
[flipButtons release];


-(void)GotoTopScreen
{
     [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```